# Wie sage ich „I brush their teeth“?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich möchte ausdrücken, dass ich morgens die Zähne meiner Töchter putze (sie sind 5 und 7 Jahre alt). Sage ich

> *Ich putze ihnen die Zähne*

oder

> *Ich putze ihre Zähne*?

Comment: Beides geht, sowohl "ich putze ihnen die Zähne" als auch "ich putze ihre Zähne".

Answer (score 8):

Wie Robert in seinem Kommentar schon bemerkt hat, sind beide Versionen gutes und richtiges Deutsch. Das funktioniert nicht nur bei den Zähnen deiner Kinder, sondern auch bei anderen Dingen:

> a) Ich wasche ihm das Auto.
>   b) Ich wasche sein Auto.
>
> a) Ich bügle ihnen die Wäsche.
>   b) Ich bügle ihre Wäsche.
>
> a) Ich putze ihnen die Zähne.
>   b) Ich putze ihre Zähne.

Es gibt zwischen a und b aber einen kleinen Bedeutungsunterschied:

**a)**
Du macht etwas für eine andere Person. Dabei steht im Vordergrund, dass du eine Arbeit erledigst, die eigentlich von der anderen Person erledigt werden sollte. Der unterstützende Aspekt deiner Tätigkeit wird mit dieser Formulierung etwas stärker betont als in der anderen Variante.

**b)**
Du verrichtest eine Tätigkeit an einem fremden Gegenstand. Hier geht es nicht darum, wer eigentlich dafür zuständig wäre, sondern es wird nur ausgedrückt, dass du etwas mit einem Ding machst, das nicht dein Ding ist. Ob das ohnehin deine Aufgabe ist, du es also ohnehin immer machst, oder ob du das machst, um die andere Person zu entlasten, bleibt in dieser Formulierung offen.

Comment: Danke vielmals, Hubert! Ich schaetze sehr die Kleinigkeiten, dass du mir erklaert hast. Es ist urwertvoll:) Danke hundertmal!

Comment: Die Erklärungen zu a) b) halte ich für Humbug und einen der 1000 Fälle von Confirmation-Bias. Man prüft nur an ein paar Beispielen ob es hinkommt, aber versucht nicht die These zu widerlegen (sondern wartet auf mich). "Ich operiere ihm das Herz. Ich operiere sein Herz." Sollte er eigentlich sein Herz selbst operieren? Ich genehmige seinen Bauantrag, ... einfach mal selbst bischen suchen.

Comment: @userunknown Auf dich hamwer grade gewartet ;)